# Finding Navigate driving directions using Google Maps in iphone

Tags: iphone

i'm developing an iPhone app which embed a mapView made with mkmapkit. I got two coordinates and I'm tracing the direction between these two points.But I need step by step directions

how can get this step by step directions if any one knows please help me .....

here i am attaching screen shot what i need:http://www.myappdemo.com/Screen%20shot.png

thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use google API for it.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Brooklyn,NY&destination=Manhattan,NY&sensor=false

Comment: thanks for u r answer ....so here i test this url i get data in xml tag in <step> but how can i get this data is there any sample source please tell me

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Brooklyn,NY&destination=Manhattan,NY&sensor=false"];
    NSData *obtainedData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
And now you can parse this xml data.